# Find longest path from a string inside a script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script and a variable `mystring` inside.
In the end of the running, `mystring` will look like this: `/dir1/dir2 /dir1/dir5/dir6 /dir1/dir9/dir20/dir99 ...` which is basically a string with different paths separated with spaces.

I need to return the depth of the longest path inside the string. Right now I have a direction but I am stuck:

I tried to insert this to my script:

```
cat $mystring | tr ' ' '\n' | sed 's/[^/]*//g' | # now print length of longest string
```

It does not recognize that I'm trying to work with the content of `$mystring`, and I also don't know how to do the last thing... Help?

Comment: Echo mystring instead of cat

Answer (score 1):

Here's the last command you're looking for:

```
wc -L
```

> -L, --max-line-length: print the maximum display width

You can also condense the `tr` and `sed` using

```
for i in $mystring; do echo $i | tr -cd /\\n; done | wc -L
```

This works as follows: loading one component of `$mystring` at a time, removes everything except a `/` or a newline, and then feeds that to the above which does the rest of the work.

By the way, can it be guaranteed that none of the paths will ever contain a space?

Answer (score 0):

If you are open for a gawk solution:

```
printf "a/b/c/d/e/f a a/b  a/b/c   a/b/c/d" |
  gawk -vFS="/" -vRS='\\s+' '{if (NF>f) f=NF;} END {print f;}'
```

Prints:

```
6
```

FS is field separator (as slash). RS is record separator (as white-space).
NF is number of fields in a given record (such as a/b/c).

Answer (score 0):

you should use array for directories to avoid space problem in path

for length of a string you can use ${#VAR}

```
DIRS=( "/tmp" "/tmp1" "/tmp/xx xxx/x1" )
MAXLENGTH=0
for LENGTH in "${DIRS[@]}"
do
    if [ "$MAXLENGTH" -lt "${#LENGTH}" ]
    then 
        MAXLENGTH="${#LENGTH}"
    fi
done
echo $MAXLENGTH
```